# How to add upload file button in custom form and send form details through Mail in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, email-templates, magento2.4.2

lI created a custom form and sending mail once submit the form.Now i need to add upload file button and send all form details through mail. i added input file tag in form but i have no idea how to configure that in controller file and email html file

Any help can be appreciated.. Thanks

```
my phtml file
```

```
<div id="popup-modal"> 
<div class="contact-form-popup" style="display:none;">

    <form class="form contact"
          action=""
          id="contact-form"
          method="post"
          data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
          data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'
          autocomplete="off">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Get in touch')) ?></span></legend>
            <div class="field note"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Simply fill in your details and enquiry below and one of our team will be in touch as soon as possible.')) ?></div>
            <div class="field firstname">
                <label class="label" for="name"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your Name:')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="required-field">Required</div>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="name" id="name" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Name')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="field emailaddress">
                <label class="label" for="emailaddress"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customer email address:')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="required-field">Required</div>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field mobile">
                <label class="label" for="mobile"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone number:')) ?></span></label>
                
                <div class="required-field">Required</div>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="mobile" id="mobile" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone number')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field postcode">
                <label class="label" for="postcode"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customer postcode:')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="required-field">Required</div>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="postcode" id="postcode" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Customer postcode')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field enquiry">
                <label class="label" for="enquiry"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Enquiry:')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <textarea name="enquiry" id="enquiry" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Enquiry')) ?>"
                        class="input-text" type="text" ></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button type="submit" id='customer-contact' title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Submit')) ?>"
                        class="action submit primary">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div style="display:none" class="static-block-message">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Get in touch')) ?></span></legend>
    <div class="field note">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Simply fill in your details and enquiry below and one of our team will be in touch as soon as possible.')) ?>
        <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Thank you. A member of our team will be in touch shortly.'))?></strong>
    </div>
    
</div>
</div>
<script>
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function($, modal) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                modalClass: 'get-in-touch',
                buttons: []
            };
            var openModal = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
            var issubmit = '<?= $_SESSION['issubmitted'];?>';
            jQuery('body').on('click', '.demo-banner .pagebuilder-button-primary', function(){
               
                jQuery('.contact-form-popup').show();
                jQuery('.static-block-message').hide();
                jQuery('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
            });

            jQuery('body').on('click', '#contact-form .action.submit', function(e){
                   
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    if(!(jQuery('#contact-form').valid())){
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if((jQuery('#contact-form').valid())){
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: '<?php echo $block->getUrl("popup/action/index") ?>',
                            data: jQuery('#contact-form').serialize(),
                            cache: false,
                            showLoader: 'true',
                            success: function(response) {
                                //alert('success');
                                jQuery('.contact-form-popup').hide();
                                jQuery('.static-block-message').show();
                                
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                
            });
        });
    }
);
</script>
```

```
my controller
```

```
<?php
namespace Apetito\Popup\Controller\Action;
 
use Zend\Log\Filter\Timestamp;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 
 
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
        /**
        * Recipient email config path
        */
        const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'contact/email/recipient_email';
        /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
        */
        protected $_transportBuilder;

        /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
        */
        protected $inlineTranslation;

        /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
        */
        protected $scopeConfig;

        /**
        * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
        */
        protected $storeManager;
        /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
        */
        protected $_escaper;

        /**
        * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
        * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
        * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
        * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
        * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
        */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
            \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
            $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
            $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->_escaper = $escaper;
        }

        /**
         * Post user question
         *
         * @return void
         * @throws \Exception
         */
        public function execute()
        {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            //print_r($post);
            //die("hello");
            if (!$post) {
                $this->_redirect('/');
                return;
            }

            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

            try {
                $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
                $postObject->setData($post);
                $error = false;

                $sender = [
                    'name' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['name']),
                    'email' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['emailaddress']),
                ];

                $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE; 
                $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                    ->setTemplateIdentifier('popup_email') // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
                    ->setTemplateOptions(
                        [
                            'area' => 'frontend',                    
                            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId() 
                        ]
                    )
                    ->setTemplateVars([
                        'name' => $post['name'],
                        'email' => $post['emailaddress'],
                        'mobile' => $post['mobile'],
                        'postcode' => $post['postcode'],
                        'enquiry' => $post['enquiry'],

                    ])
                    ->setFrom($sender)
                    ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                    ->addTo('mani@gmail.com')
                  
                    ->getTransport();

                    $transport->sendMessage();
                    $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
                    //$this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                    //    __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
                    //);
                    //$resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
                   //$this->_redirect('/');
                    return;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
               // $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.'.$e->getMessage())
               //);
                //$resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());

               //$this->_redirect('/');
                return;
            }
        }

}
```

```
template file
```

```
<!--@subject customer  Enquiry @-->
 
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<table>
     <tr class="email-intro">
         <tr>
            Customer Name : {{var name}}
         </tr>
         <tr>
            Customer Email Address : {{var email}}
         </tr>
         <tr>
            Phone Number : {{var mobile}}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            Customer Postcode : {{var postcode}}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            Customer Enquiry : {{var enquiry}}
        </tr>
     </tr>
 </table>
 
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

About your issue you can use this module for reference.

https://github.com/ansarhusain7/Custom-mail-with-attachment-magento2/tree/master/CustomForm/MailAttachment

I Hope This Helps You.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @jigar. I go through this module. Its not working for Magento 2.4. It showing error - "Zend\Mime\PartFactory" does not exit. Any idea how to rectify this?

Comment: @Mani you need to just give reference from this module for your issue.I am checked is working fine with magento 2.3.